# Change scope of local variable by decorators?

Tags: python, global-variables, python-decorators

I have a method that set the `name` variable but there isn't `global name` at the first line of it, It uses local `name` variable so It never changes the global `name` variable.
Is there any way that by decorating `set_name` force it to use global `name`?

```
name = "John"

def set_name():
    name = "Sara"

def print_name():
    global name
    print(name)

def decorator(func):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        ## Problem:
        # Force set_name to use global 'name'
        func(*args, **kwargs)

    return wrapper

print_name()
#Output: John

decorator(set_name)()

print_name()
# Prints John, but I want to prints Sara
```

Comment: Perhaps there is some sort of deep Python magic to do this, but the short answer is no.  Decorators don't change the function they wrap.

Comment: I dont think you can do this ... tbh I have a hard time seeing why you would want to do this

Comment: You appear to be defining a class with `set_name` and `print_name` methods without actually declaring a class.

Answer (score 2):

No, unless the decorator takes the function's code (bytecode from the function's code object, or source code using `inspect`), changes it, creates a new code object from the changed code and replaces the function's code with that. Which is, of course, highly unreliable, hacky, implementation-specific and deep black magic. Just add `global name` (or eliminate the global variable altogether).

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is: no.

A bit extended answer: no, not in a portable way. Technically, you could play around with the CPython bytecode, but

- that will not run on any other interpreter,
- nobody will be able to understand that code,
- the headache won't be worth it.

Answer (score 0):

```
name = "John" #global name
```

and name inside set_name():

```
name = "Sara" #local name
```

To use global name inside function `set_name()` do like:

```
def set_name():
   global name
   name = "Sara"
```

Comment: Thanks, but I mean by decorating.

Answer (score 0):

Define a class that wraps `name`:

```
class Person(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = "John"

    def set_name(self):
        self.name = "Sara"

    def print_name(self):
        print(name)

p = Person()
p.print_name()   # Prints John
p.set_name()     # Changes name to Sara
p.print_name()   # Prints Sara
```

A class which hard-codes its attribute values like this is, of course, a little silly, but this demonstrates the purpose of a class: to encapsulate data (`name`) and the functions (`set_name`, `print_name`) that operate on it.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, why you are trying to decorate the setter.

You can do something like this, but I would not recommend it as a usual style of coding:

```
name = "John"

def print_name():
    print name

def decorator(func, tmp_name):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        global name
        old_name = name
        name = tmp_name
        func(*args, **kwargs)
        name = old_name
    return wrapper

print_name()
decorator(print_name, 'Sarah')()
print_name()
```

Output:

```
John
Sarah
John
```